# setting up a Ubuntu desktop on an Ubuntu server

Tags: server, vnc

Suppose I start with [www.linode.com](http://www.linode.com) and instantiate one `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` server and then this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon 
           metacity nautilus gnome-terminal vnc4server gufw
```

These programs (such as ubuntu-desktop) are recommended [in this tutorial on using VNC to get a desktop on Ubuntu servers](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Upon a boot the result has this kind of look:
[image: remote desktop]

When I click the Ubuntu logo in the top left, instead of a "search your computer" prompt which I would get on a "normal Ubuntu for Desktop" physical machine, instead, I get the menu that you see. Without the search it is inconvenient to run `gufw`. Looking into that menu and each of the submenus I see no `gufw`. I resorted to opening a terminal and typing `sudo gufw` (which might be a mistake because I recall that I'm not supposed to sudo a graphical program so perhaps I should stop using the sudo prefix). This is not convenient. I might run into other limitations in the future.

How would I get a normal (or nearly normal) Ubuntu desktop with the search feature?

Comment: ubuntu -desktop is a horrible way to manage servers. Managing servers is editing config files, start/stop services, and such and can be done via ssh. If you need a graphical interface use one of the many web options such as webmin, phpmyadmin, cockpit, etc.

Comment: Mostly I'm not managing servers. I'm wanting to use an Ubuntu desktop remotely. Administration is a very small part of what I do. Since I need the desktop no matter what (for my application), I might as well use it for the very little admin that I do. There's only 1 user, and no MySQL. In that case the tools you mention (webmin, phymyadmin) will not be worth learning.

Comment: You can forward your single app over ssh. And why are you running a server to run a desktop application remotely ? makes no sense. One would assume you are running some server ;). Also, if you insist on desktop / VNC I highly suggest freenx , it is faster and more secure.

Comment: If I use ssh without Ubuntu desktop, the application will probably crash when it tries to paint the screen. If I limit myself to doing things that are only text based then I can use ssh but if the job takes 400 hours that means my local machine has to keep an ssh window open for 400 hours. The nice thing about VNC is that you can close the window and come back the next day and make a new window and it will look the same as how you left it previously. I think that's not possible with ssh.

Comment: ssh + screen or similar.

Comment: Your last comment is a little cryptic.

Comment: screen allows you to detach ssh sessions similar to how you use VNC. See https://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind, however, in the interest of consistency (simplicity), I prefer that everything I can do locally can also be done remotely. That means the availability of a graphical Ubuntu desktop is a preference.

Comment: Look at my answer - guessing you did not select Unity from the cog.  It appears you are running the MATE DE.  @H2ONaCl

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use tasksel to install the default ubuntu‑desktop so that it works as it would if you had installed it alongside the OS.

After installing tasksel you should be able to run it with sudo, and then just select the ubuntu‑desktop collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a shell and execute:

```
sudo apt install gnome xorg ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

That's all, however, *you probably did not select Unity from the cog that allows you to choose the DE.*  Moreover, I do find installing the entire Gnome api and xorg helps.

Comment: I've done this so many times it hurts - trust me, it works just like ^

Comment: There's still no "gufw" or "firewall" in a menu. The "System Tools > Prefs > Main Menu > SystemSettings" setup does have gufw checkbox. It is already selected. That dialog itself does not offer a way to launch it. It only offers a way to "move down" to reorder the list but it doesn't work.  Parallel to gufw is "Printers" but when you use the desktop the Printers appears in "Sundry", not "System Settings". In fact there is no menu called "System Settings". If gufw is parallel to Printers, then they should both appeari n "Sundry" but that is not the case. This system looks chaotic.

Comment: There is no cog to select Unity. The "Accessories" now has "Desktop Search" but that only finds files. There is still no search feature to invoke applications.

Comment: Old version of server perhaps or 32 bit?

Comment: It's 16.04 and 64 bit.

Comment: Alright I’ll try to retest sorry this is happening!  Will keep you posted!